# "Please specify the product's option(s)" in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, configurable-product

I've a Magento 1.9 server and the products is set on, the adding into cart for simple product is working smoothly and fine, but when I try to add configurable product this message return.

> Please specify the product's option(s).

Now I was tracing the code and working on it, till I reach here.

> app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController

in this file this code for adding the product exists:

```
/**
 * Add product to shopping cart action
 *
 * @return Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function addAction()
{
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_goBack();
        return;
    }
    $cart   = $this->_getCart();
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    try {
        if (isset($params['qty'])) {
            $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
            );
            $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);


        }

        $product = $this->_initProduct();
        $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');


        /**
         * Check product availability
         */
        if (!$product) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }
        echo 'here';
        ?>
            <pre>
                <?php print_r($params); ?>
            </pre>
        <?php
            exit;
        ?>
        <?php

        $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        if (!empty($related)) {
            $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
        }

        $cart->save();

        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

        /**
         * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
         */
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
        );

        if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
            if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
            }
            $this->_goBack();
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
            $this->_getSession()->addNotice(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
        } else {
            $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($message));
            }
        }

        $url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
        if ($url) {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        } else {
            $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.'));
        Mage::logException($e);
        $this->_goBack();
    }
}
```

In this code I used this simple code to achieve where I am and what data I have.

```
echo 'here';
?>
    <pre>
        <?php print_r($params); ?>
    </pre>
<?php
    exit;
?>
<?php
```

This simple code return the arguments I have for my Configurable Product.

```
Array
(
    [uenc] => aHR0cDovL3N0YWdpbmcudmF0dHJlbmEuY29tL2luZGV4LnBocC9nZW5lcmFsLWplYW5zMTMuaHRtbA,,
    [product] => 65
    [form_key] => qIGyp6YDp7kQjibA
    [related_product] => 
    [super_attribute] => Array
        (
            [168] => M
        )

    [qty] => 1
)
```

That mean all attributes is chosen, but after this simple code when I reach the

```
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
```

it suppose to go to this file

> app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php

On this function

```
/**
 * Add product to shopping cart (quote)
 *
 * @param   int|Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $productInfo
 * @param   mixed $requestInfo
 * @return  Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart
 */
public function addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo=null)
{
    $product = $this->_getProduct($productInfo);
    $request = $this->_getProductRequest($requestInfo);

    $productId = $product->getId();

    if ($product->getStockItem()) {
        $minimumQty = $product->getStockItem()->getMinSaleQty();
        //If product was not found in cart and there is set minimal qty for it
        if ($minimumQty && $minimumQty > 0 && $request->getQty() < $minimumQty
            && !$this->getQuote()->hasProductId($productId)
        ){
            $request->setQty($minimumQty);
        }
    }

    if ($productId) {
        try {
            $result = $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $request);
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->getCheckoutSession()->setUseNotice(false);
            $result = $e->getMessage();
        }
        /**
         * String we can get if prepare process has error
         */
        if (is_string($result)) {
            $redirectUrl = ($product->hasOptionsValidationFail())
                ? $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl(
                    $product,
                    array('_query' => array('startcustomization' => 1))
                )
                : $product->getProductUrl();
            $this->getCheckoutSession()->setRedirectUrl($redirectUrl);
            if ($this->getCheckoutSession()->getUseNotice() === null) {
                $this->getCheckoutSession()->setUseNotice(true);
            }
            Mage::throwException($result);
        }
    } else {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('The product does not exist.'));
    }

    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after', array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));
    $this->getCheckoutSession()->setLastAddedProductId($productId);
    return $this;
}
```

But when I try to `echo` anything in this function, it won't appear and redirected to the configurable product page with this message:

> Please specify the product's option(s).

**UPDATE 1:**

```
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/product');
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
<?php if (count($_attributes) > 0):?>
    <dl>
    <?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute):?>
    <div class="row">
        <h2 class="gws_p_title" style="border-top:  none;"><?php echo $this->__($_attribute->getLabel()) ?><em>*</em></h2>
        <dd class="last">
            <div class="input-box">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select js-example-basic-single">
                    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                  </select>
              </div>
        </dd>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was issue for me and take a lot of time from me since i'm new to magento.

adding this line in the front of the file

> app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/cofigurable.phtml

```
$attValConfig = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
```

so after search and check every code i have, i found the error in these lines.

```
<select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select js-example-basic-single">
    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
</select>
```

**IT SHOULD BE LIKE THIS**

```
<select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select js-example-basic-single">
<option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
<?php
foreach ($attValConfig as $values) {
    foreach ($values['values'] as $value) {
       ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $value['value_index']; ?>"><?php echo $this->__($value['label']); ?></option>
       <?php

    }
}
?>
</select>
```

**AND NOW EVERYTHING WORK VERY FINE**

Answer (score 1):

Please specify the product's option(s).

This error comes when your product have some custom options that are required ,but not selected at the time of add to cart or in case of configurable product configurable options (like color or size) is not selected while add to cart. Make sure you have created configurable options correctly.

Do you created product by import, because configurable options are not imported by magento import profile. You need to check this thing in you admin-> catalog->product open the product that is not working. You need to check that product have some configurable options or not.

if product have options, you need to check that product that are assign to that option should be enabled and in stock for that store.

If you do not have any customization on configurable product, this much operation will be enough to find a solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, what happen here is that my configurable has size configurable option and when i select it and select the quantity and press add to cart this error occur, i've check the config option and i checked the product and everything seems right to me.

Comment: and i solve the problem here,, with all of my research and check all the code in phtml files. please check the update and the answer i gave.